# perform 2-d operation on each layer of a 3-d stack

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a three dimensional numpy array, for example, an RGB image.

I want to perform the same two dimensional operation on each layer of the array; for example standard deviation, or sum.

Without using a `for` loop, is there a simple numpy or scipy command to perform the operation, returning a numpy array?

ex:
the three layers of a numpy array are:

```
myArray[:,:,0] = [[1,2],[3,4]] 
myArray[:,:,1] = [[0,0],[1,1]]  
myArray[:,:,2] = [[4,4],[4,4]]
```

imagine a command `numpy.sumLayers()`

```
numpy.sumLayers(myArray) = array([[10],[2],[16]])
```

or similarly `numpy.standardDeviationLayers()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each layer of 3D stack would mean axes `0` and `1` being combined for each index in `axis=2`. So, to solve your case, you can use [`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) and [`np.std`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) along the axes `0`,`1`, like so -

```
sum_val = myArray.sum(axis=(0,1))

std_val = myArray.std(axis=(0,1))
```

You can also perform the summation more efficiently with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
sum_val = np.einsum('ijk->k',myArray) # k represents axis = 2
```

Sample run -

```
In [11]: myArray
Out[11]: 
array([[[ 1.,  0.,  4.],
        [ 2.,  0.,  4.]],

       [[ 3.,  1.,  4.],
        [ 4.,  1.,  4.]]])

In [12]: myArray.sum(axis=(0,1))
Out[12]: array([ 10.,   2.,  16.])

In [13]: myArray.std(axis=(0,1))
Out[13]: array([ 1.11803399,  0.5       ,  0.        ])

In [14]: np.einsum('ijk->k',myArray)
Out[14]: array([ 10.,   2.,  16.])
```

Comment: So easy... I knew it would be. Thank you very much for your time and for introducing me to Einstein sums.. pretty cool stuff.